# Kafka Consumer seektoBeginning

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I did not use a partition to publish to Kafka topic. 
    ProducerRecord(String topic, K key, V value)

In the consumer, I would like to go to the beginning. 
    seekToBeginning(Collection partitions)

Is it possible to seek to beginning without using a partition? Does Kafka assign a default partition?

https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.html
https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

Comment: Didnt get your question , if you are publishing it will land up in a partition

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When producing, if you don't explicitely specify a partition, the producer will pick one automatically from your topic.

In your consumer, if your are subscribed to your topic, you can seek to the start of all the partitions your consumer is currently assigned to using:

```
consumer.seekToBeginning(consumer.assignment())
```

Comment: Mike, understood. I was wondering if there is a default partition selected by the producer or Kafka itself.

Comment: Assuming you didn't change the Partitioner (`partitioner.class`) in your Producer, the partition is selected using round robin for messages without keys or by hashing the key for keyed messages. See https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/DefaultPartitioner.java#L44-L71