# KafkaConsumer is not consuming messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

From what I've read so far the consumer should consume the messages properly but the only output I get are the '.'

```
public class KafkaConsumerSample {

public static void main(String []args) {
    runProducer();
    //runConsumer();
}

static void runProducer() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());

    Producer<Long, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<Long, String>(props);

     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         producer.send(new ProducerRecord<Long, String>("foo", "test message" + Integer.toString(i)));
     }
     producer.close();
}

static void runConsumer() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group-id");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    KafkaConsumer<Long, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<Long, String>(props); 
    consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("foo"));

    while(true) {
        ConsumerRecords<Long, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        System.out.println(".");
        for(ConsumerRecord<Long, String> record: records) {
            System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Kafka log tells me the following:

> Member consumer-1 in groupp test has failed, removing it from the
>   group
>
> Preparing to rebalance group test with old generation 21
>
> Group test with generation 22 is now empty

I don't really understand what this means. What am I missing? It looks very straightforward to me.

**update**

I would like to read all offsets once when I run the consumer. From offset 0 to the latest offset. I tried :

```
static void runConsumer() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group-id");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, OffsetResetStrategy.EARLIEST.toString().toLowerCase());
        KafkaConsumer<Long, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<Long, String>(props); 
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("foo"));


        while(true) {
            consumer.seekToBeginning(consumer.assignment());
            ConsumerRecords<Long, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(5));

            System.out.println(".");
            for(ConsumerRecord<Long, String> record: records) {
                System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
            }
        }
    }
```

Just setting AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG to earliest isnt enough apparently. I ran the consumer once and it printed all offsets from 0 to latest but now it doesnt anymore after running it again ? Not sure I understand this config properly. Which is why I added the consumer.seek() method but where exactly do I place this? If I place it within the while(true) loop as shown it prints everything from offset 0 to latest but not every 5 seconds but rather without any break..constantly spamming my console.

Comment: but according to here  your consumer groupid is `group-id`, where did this `groupp test` came from

Comment: Insure, that you have set property `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` to `OffsetResetStrategy.EARLIEST.toString().toLowerCase()`. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53867775/kafka-consumer-not-returning-any-events/53869137#53869137

Comment: You might want to separate your producer and consumer code as well into two classes. In a real-world scenario they will be separate. Then you could have one while loop with a producer, and another with a consumer, then you'd be seeing messages because the consumer could then start from the end of the topic, and wait for producer to send messages

Comment: thank you. This did somehow work but i am not sure if I fully understand it. I read the docs and if I understand it correctly if there is no offset found (how can this happen anyways? beacuse I am not looking at a specific offset, am I?) then it takes the earliest one which is what exactly? 0? what does earliest mean? Also what is the difference between this config and consumer.seek()? What if I want to read all offsets from 0 to the latest everytime i consume? I tried to make this work (see edit in main post) but there is a problem.

Comment: @cricket_007 updated my post

Comment: The `auto.offset.reset` only applies when a consumer group does not exist. Earliest is literally what it means. Read from the oldest un-consumed offset, which could be 0, but not always (offset 0 can expire). If you **always** want to read from the beginning, you need to explicitly seek to the beginning - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49723182/kafka-consumer-seektobeginning but note that your topic data can expire eventually, so you will want to maybe disable that, or not rely on Kafka holding that data forever

Comment: @cricket_007 i guess I am just confused why my consumer won't consume any messages when the seek() method is outside the while(true) loop.

Comment: well interesting, apparently partitions have to be assigned first. So calling consumer.poll() first is a must! Didn't read this anywhere but good to know.